# How to get contact change, add and remove with URI provided by system call back onChange android?

Tags: android

I am building an app , there is a requirement of notifying app when a new contact added or existing contact gets edited or removed. Although a lot of questions are already available those have answers as well. But my question is little bit different. I am using approach of Content Observer as mentioned below in the code

```
ContactChangeObserver contactChangeObserver = new ContactChangeObserver(this, new Handler());
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, contactChangeObserver);
```

and in ContactChangeObserver class I am overriding onChange() method as it was already recommended in many of the post. Code is mentioned below

```
public class ContactChangeObserver extends ContentObserver {

private Context mContext;
public ContactChangeObserver(Context context, Handler handler) {
    super(handler);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
    super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
    List<ContactsModel> listOfDBContact = new ChildTrackingDB().getAllContacts(ChildTrackingDB.getInstance(mContext));
    List<ContactsModel> listOfCellPhoneContact = ContactUtility.readContactDirectoryOfPhone(mContext);
    if (listOfCellPhoneContact.size() == listOfDBContact.size()) {
        //this is edit case
    } else  if (listOfCellPhoneContact.size() > listOfDBContact.size()) {
        //this is add case

    }else  {
        //this is remove case
    }
}
```

}

I am getting call back of onChange() as expected(in all cases of adding, removing and editing case). As mentioned in above example, I am overriding onChange() that has URI param. And when I get call back i also receive uri as well. my question is that can that uri be useful to only get that contact which got changed or added? The uri I am getting is

```
content://com.android.contacts
```

In my example code, if contact is edited and the device has let's suppose more than thousands contacts then it is a very time consuming to iterate over each contact.Or is there any better approach available for the problem.

Comment: did my answer help you in anyway? You didn't give any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar kind of problem. First of all the **Uri** which you are getting in `onChange()` method is vague. From my previous encounter I can tell, You won't be able to detect which contact got inserted, updated or deleted. So yes it becomes very time-consuming to detect which contact to get and perform Crud.

To answer your second question, I would suggest you to use `Set` instead of `List`. Here is a sample class which you might helpful. It's a linear operation and i've tested it with 2-3k+ data. And it performs well.

```
public class AddressBookObserver extends ContentObserver {

private static final String TAG = "AddressBookObserver";
private static final String FLAG_INSERT = "INSERT";
private static final String FLAG_DELETE = "DELETE";

private long lastTimeOfCall = 0L;
private long lastTimeOfUpdate = 0L;
private long threshold_time = 5000;
private WeakReference<Context> mContextWeakReference;

public AddressBookObserver(Handler handler, Context context) {
    super(handler);
    this.mContextWeakReference = new WeakReference<Context>(context);
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    onChange(selfChange, null);
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onChange() Address Book Changed!");

    lastTimeOfCall = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Set<String> phoneBookSet = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> providerSet = new HashSet<>();

    if (checkContactPermission() && (lastTimeOfCall - lastTimeOfUpdate > threshold_time) && General.getIsContactListImported(mContextWeakReference.get())) {
        lastTimeOfUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();

        phoneBookSet.addAll(getOnlyPhoneNumbers());
        providerSet.addAll(getProviderNumbers());

        int bookCount = phoneBookSet.size();
        int providerCount = providerSet.size();

        Log.e(TAG, "onChange: bookCount: " + bookCount + " providerCount: " + providerCount);


        if (bookCount > providerCount) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onChange() Insert!");
            phoneBookSet.removeAll(providerSet);
            String val = phoneBookSet.toString().replaceAll("[\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]", "");
            Log.w(TAG, "value to insert: " + val);
            //DO Insert Operations

        } else if (bookCount < providerCount) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onChange() DELETE!");
            providerSet.removeAll(phoneBookSet);
            String val = providerSet.toString().replaceAll("[\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]", "");
            Log.w(TAG, "value to delete: " + val);
            //Do Delete Operations
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "onChange() UPDATE!");
            Set<String> tempPhoneBookSet = new HashSet<>();
            tempPhoneBookSet.addAll(phoneBookSet);

            phoneBookSet.removeAll(providerSet);
            String newData = phoneBookSet.toString().replaceAll("[\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]", "");
            Log.e(TAG, "newData: " + newData);

            providerSet.removeAll(tempPhoneBookSet);
            String deleteData = providerSet.toString().replaceAll("[\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]", "");
            Log.e(TAG, "deleteData: " + deleteData);

            if (!newData.equals(deleteData)) {
                //DO Update Operations
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "onChange() Nothing to update!");
            }
        }
    } else if (!checkContactPermission()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onChange() Contact Permission not granted!");
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "onChange() Time threshold not reached Or Contacts not imported yet!");
    }

}

private boolean checkContactPermission() {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContextWeakReference.get(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

/**
 * Get only phone numbers from device's addressBook
 *
 * @return - Set of distinct phone numbers
 */
private Set<String> getOnlyPhoneNumbers() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getOnlyPhoneNumbers()");
    Cursor phones = mContextWeakReference.get().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " ASC");

    Set<String> uniquePhoneContacts = new HashSet<>();

    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).replaceAll("\\D", "");
        String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
        String photoUri = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));

        if (uniquePhoneContacts.add(id + "," + name + "," + photoUri + "," + phoneNumber)) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Book#" + id + "," + name + "," + photoUri + "," + phoneNumber);
        }
    }
    phones.close();
    return uniquePhoneContacts;

}

/**
 * Get all the Contacts from provider which are not deletable
 *
 * @return - All distinct phone numbers from app's provider
 */
private Set<String> getProviderNumbers() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getProviderNumbers()");
    Cursor phones = mContextWeakReference.get().getContentResolver().query(MyContactProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, PhoneContactController.COL_IS_DELETABLE + "=?",
            new String[]{"0"}, MyContactProvider.COL_CONTACT_ID + " ASC");
    Set<String> uniquePhoneContacts = new HashSet<>();
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(MyContactProvider.COL_CONTACT_ID));
        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(MyContactProvider.COL_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(MyContactProvider.COL_CONTACT_NO));
        String photoUri = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(MyContactProvider.COL_PHOTO_URI));

        if (uniquePhoneContacts.add(id + "," + name + "," + photoUri + "," + phoneNumber)) {
            Log.w(TAG, "QueryProvider#" + id + "," + name + "," + photoUri + "," + phoneNumber);
        }
    }
    phones.close();
    return uniquePhoneContacts;
}

}
```

I hope this helps.